# Load local HTML file(from assets) to a String

Tags: android, html, string

How can I load a local html file(from assets folder) to a String?
I tried this code but the result is only "?????...".

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("aaa.html");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
String str = new String(buffer);
System.out.println(str);
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not reading the whole file. Try this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while(is.read(buffer) != -1) {
    builder.append(new String(buffer));
}
is.close();
String str = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. but it loads some extra characters at the end of string. how can I fix it?

Comment: well I fixed it by adding: int size = 
is.available(); 
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

Answer (score 0):

try this......

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/yuor_file.html");        
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String linewise = br.readLine();

while(linewise != null) {
  sb.append(linewise );
  sb.append("\n");
  linewise = br.readLine();
}
//now data in sb
```

Comment: please, do not post answers that are not tested, not working and thus useless